# How to build level in Blender using assets from Unity?

Tags: unity, 3d, blender, level-design, levels

There are already models for level creation that are used to create different levels. I want to use them to create a new level and I want to assemble the level in Blender.

But if I just import the models into Blender from which I assemble the levels there, and then export the finished level to Unity, then it turns out that I will create duplicate models from which the levels are assembled.

How to assemble a level in Blender in such a situation, avoiding duplication of models when importing?

Comment: What benefits are you trying to gain to import all models in Blender, build your level and export it back in Unity compared to build it directly in Unity?

Comment: @Zibelas It seems to me that it is more convenient to collect the level in Blender

Comment: Blender is a software to create your model (singular) as an asset used in Unity to build for game/ application. You will have more problems if you create a huge model in Blender and try to get the bits working in Unity. Want to pick up something from the table? Too bad all items are belonging to one model. How to manage interactions? Or culling? Memory management?